# iOS segue identifier is empty string in prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, identifier

I have a segue with identifier.

[image]

When I press the button in function shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier I get an empty identifier

[image]

What can cause such problem? What did I set up wrong?

Here is my code:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {

    if identifier == segueIdentifier {
        return false
    }
    else if identifier == registrationSegueidentifier {
        if checkEULA() == true {
            return true
        }
        else {
            showEULAToUser()
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Did you use performSegueWithIdentifier ?

Comment: put this in the function and please give the out put print(identifier)

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva print(identifier) prints an empty output. It is the same as in debuger

Comment: Try to delete the segue and rename it.

Comment: @Ro22e0 This segue I setup in storyboard and I don't call it from code.

Comment: Trying using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could had localized your storyboard,so the results is that now you have two storyboards.So you added identifier to the base storyboard and maybe you forgot to add this identifier to the another storyboard. Do research in this direction.

Comment: This was the case. I already found my mistake, but forgot to post here.
I'll accept this as an right answer